# Search by BLOB Image in mySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, blob

I'm trying to search one of my tables however by using the BLOB image.

So for instance, I need to get info of another column using the BLOB as an identifier.

Not sure if this can be done.

Im my example, I'm trying to retrieve my ArtistID using the blob assosciated with that artist.

Do i need to search via the base64 encoded version?

Any guidance will help :)

```
$sql =  "SELECT ArtistID FROM artistlocation WHERE img = ****** ";
```

Comment: What about calculating SHA1 (or MD5) hash of image in php and use it in query: SELECT ArtistID FROM artistlocation WHERE sha1(img)='your_image_hash' ?